# automated interlinking pages with hyperlink in umbraco

Tags: open-source, umbraco6

I want to use an existing umbraco package ,where i can automate interlinking of Umbraco contents Just like wikipedia.

Is there anything in umbraco for automated interlinking pages with hyperlink, anchor text, which can be further moderated manually ?

if not, any suggestions how can i automate interlinking of existing contents of Umbraco pages one inside another.

Comment: You will have to crawl the parent child relationship and make use of relations. Perhaps [this link](https://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/12/7/getting-to-know-umbraco-relations) will help.